# Obtain a random sample from a sum of two dependent random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, sampling

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are dependent random variables and I know the marginal densities of $X$ and $Y$ (if simple we can assume they are Gaussian). Using a copula I may be able to estimate the joint density of $X$ and $Y$.

How can I obtain a random sample from $Z = X + Y$?

Comment: sample pairs from the joint distribution of (X,Y) and add them

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry for the confusion. I know only the marginals. And using these I might be able to compute an empirical copula. How can I use it to compute a sample from $X+Y$

Comment: Model the copula, estimate it, then sample from the estimated joint distribution?

Comment: Use whatever sample you are planning on estimating the copula from, and add those pairs; you have a sample from the sum right away without simulating anything.

Comment: @Glen_b I am bit new to Copula. Can you explain your answer bit more. I need several samples from Z. I have several realizations from X and Y. I need to obtain several samples of Z. So, how do you say that adding realizations of X and Y gives realizations of Z?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sample+copula+answers%3A1+score%3A1.